# Left, center, and right justification within a single cell

Tags: output-formatting, cells, style, alignment

I can write a cell with the text alignment on the right:

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
 Cell["On the right", "Subsection", TextAlignment -> Right]]
```

or likewise on the `Left` or in the `Center`.

As I change the display width of the cell, the alignment behaves as expected.  Great.

My request, though, is to place text at the same elevation or line in a ***SINGLE*** cell, some of it left justified, some of it center justified, and some of it right justified, which retains the justification as I interactively change the width of the notebook window, and hence of the cell.  (This requirement of being on the same line precludes "solutions" that place three separate rows atop each other, each with a separate `TextAlignment`.)

This attempt doesn't work (for fairly obvious reasons), but it may clarify what I'm seeking:

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],
 BoxData[RowBox[
   {Cell["make left justified", "Subsection", TextAlignment -> Left],
    Cell["make center justified", "Subsection", TextAlignment -> Center], 
    Cell["make right justified", "Subsection", TextAlignment -> Right]}]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expr = Column[{Pane["make left justified", Full, Alignment -> Left], 
    Pane["make center justified", Full, Alignment -> Center], 
    Pane["make right justified", Full, Alignment -> Right]}];
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes@expr], "Subsection"]]
```

> [image: screenshot]

---

> The lines must be on the same elevation, not one beneath the other.

```
expr = Overlay[{Pane["left", Full, Alignment -> Left], 
    Pane["center", Full, Alignment -> Center], Pane["right", Full, Alignment -> Right]}];
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes@expr], "Subsection"]]
```

> [image: screenshot]

Alternatively,

```
expr = Grid[{{Pane["left", Full, Alignment -> Left], 
     Pane["center", Full, Alignment -> Center], Pane["right", Full, Alignment -> Right]}}];
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes@expr], "Subsection"]]
```

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks but no.  The lines must be on the same elevation, not one beneath the other.  (I'll clarify in the question.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I updated the answer.

Comment: Hah!  Very clever.  *OVERLAP* three cells.  Wish I had thought of that.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is:

```
Pane[
    Grid[
        {{left, center, right}},
        ItemSize->Fit,
        Alignment->{{Left, Center, Right}, Baseline}
    ],
    ImageSize->Full
]
```

Comment: Oh... I was unaware of `ItemSize->Fit`.  Very useful.  (+1)

Comment: Removing the `Pane` I get the same output.

Comment: `ItemSize->Fit` seems to be undocumented. I cannot find it on either the Docs page for `Grid` or `ItemSize`.

Comment: So basically instead of having to type `ItemSize -> {Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1/3], Scaled[1/3]}`, like I have doing for a long time, I can now just type `ItemSize -> Fit`. This is nice, reminds me of LaTeX hfill.
By the way,  `ItemSize -> "Fit"` also works...