# Create SlideShow notebook with docked "header" cell with left-, center-, and right-justified portions

Tags: slideshows, docked-cell

I previously asked how to make a cell containing left-, center-, and right-justified elements, [answered here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272286/left-center-and-right-justification-within-a-single-cell).  How does one create a slideshow notebook with such a banner locked in place, such that when the user changes the window size these justifications are retained?  Moreover, the banner must appear at the top of *every* slide.

Here's a minimal example attempt at what I seek... though the created notebook does not have the desired docked cell:

```
leftImage = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
rightImage = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Girl"}];

myBanner = Grid[{{
     Pane[ImageResize[leftImage, 100], Full, Alignment -> Left],
     Pane[Text[Style["Center text", Italic]], Full, 
      Alignment -> Center],
     Pane[ImageResize[rightImage, 100], Full, Alignment -> Right]}}, 
   Background -> GrayLevel[.92]];

nb = NotebookCreate[ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow", 
  DockedCells -> 
   Dynamic[If[
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment] === 
      "SlideShow", {Inherited, myBanner}, myBanner]]]
```

Comment: The option setting for DockedCells should be a Cell object, so something like `DockedCells->Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ myBanner` should work.

Comment: Almost... almost...  Your version creates a one-slide document but does not allow the creation of multiple slides, each with the same desired docked header.  Test your version to see the problem.

Comment: does this give what you need: `With[{dc = Cell@ToBoxes@myBanner}, 
 nb = NotebookCreate[ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow", 
  DockedCells ->  Dynamic[If[ CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment] ===   "SlideShow", {Inherited, dc}, dc]]]]`?

Comment: @kglr:  Oh... you are *so* close.  Your code indeed gives what I seek, but it has one small glitch:  It does not preserve full function of the slide selection pull-down menu at the top left of the toolbar.  I create three slides (say), and that toolbar pulldown lists only slide 1.  If you fix that, and post your code as an answer, then I'll accept it... and the world will be a better place!

Comment: @kglr:  My mistake... one need merely click ***and hold*** to get the full pulldown list.  So if you want a quick 100 reputation points, post your code and I'll accept it!

Comment: @David, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basen on comments above the following gives the desired result:

```
With[{dc = Cell @ ToBoxes @ myBanner},  
  nb = NotebookCreate[ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow",    
  DockedCells ->  
   Dynamic[If[
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment] === "SlideShow",
     {Inherited, dc}, dc]]]]
```